# launching Bluetooth settings

Tags: android

is there any way to launch Bluetooth setting in android , 
for example user clicks on a button on my program and will go to Bluetooth setting .

is there any way to launch other options like WIFI settings , GPS settings ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is. Just start the Settings app via intent and `startActivity()` method. Check out the [`Setting`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) class for reference for the `Intent`s.

For Example in an Activity (pseudo code):

```
public void onStartBluetoothSettingsClick() {   
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS)); 
}
```